# What is bloomberg's response when one of a few fields is not found?

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

I have a Java code that uses blpapi to request specific fields of specific securities. My code runs fine now. However, I have thought of a case that is not being handled by my current code.

Say, for example, I am requesting 'CUR_MKT_CAP', 'PX_LAST', and 'EQY_SH_OUT' for a specific security. What if Bloomberg does not have the value for 'PX_LAST'? What will Bloomberg give me then?
(a) Will it give me a field Element where PX_LAST = 0? 
(b) Will it give me a field Element where PX_LAST = NULL?
(c) Will it not include PX_LAST to the response that I will receive? Thus, the response will look like this?

```
HistoricalDataResponse (choice) = {
    securityData = {
        security = XXXXX Equity
        sequenceNumber = 0
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = YYYY-MM-DD
                CUR_MKT_CAP = XX.XXXX
                EQY_SH_OUT = XX.XXXX
            }
        }
    } }
```

Basically, I just want to know how I should handle if one of the fields I need is not given by Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, if a field returns no data, it will be omitted from the `fieldData` element. If none of the fields returns data, the `fieldData` will be empty:

```
ReferenceDataResponse = {
    securityData[] = {
        securityData = {
            security = "MSFT US Equity"
            eidData[] = {
            }
            fieldExceptions[] = {
            }
            sequenceNumber = 0
            fieldData = {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily test this, for example using `MSFT US Equity / YAS_BOND_YLD`.

Comment: I tested it using the example you mentioned. It gave me the responses I just posted as an answer since it was too long as a comment. =)
However, is there anyway where I can test if out of three fields I requested only 2 fields were provided by Bloomberg as a response?

Comment: @Krish In your answer, you seem to have used YAS_BOND_YLD as a security (hence the error) - I suggested requesting the ***fields*** YAS_BOND_YLD for the ***security*** MSFT US Equity. You will see that the `fieldData[]` element will exist but be empty. If you add more fields, the fieldData[] element will look like `fieldData = { date = 2016-08-29; PX_LAST = 58.1; PX_VOLUME = 1.6417207E7 }` and the field(s) without data will be ignored.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm going to try that and post the result here. Thank you @assylias

Answer (score 0):

I tested it using @assylias's answer. It gave me the following results.

MSFT US Equity

```
HistoricalDataResponse (choice) = {
    securityData = {
        security = MSFT US Equity
        sequenceNumber = 0
    }
}
```

YAS_BOND_YLD

```
HistoricalDataResponse (choice) = {
    securityData = {
        security = YAS_BOND_YLD
        sequenceNumber = 0
        securityError = {
            source = 500::bbdbh5
            code = 15
            category = BAD_SEC
            message = Unknown/Invalid securityInvalid Security [nid:500] 
            subcategory = INVALID_SECURITY
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @assylias comment, I used YAS_BOND_YLD as a field. And blpapi returned the following as a response.

My input to the request:

```
Ticker: XXX XX Equity Start/End Date: 20160818 Fields: CUR_MKT_CAP YAS_BOND_YLD PX_LAST EQY_SH_OUT
```

BLPAPI's response is,

```
HistoricalDataResponse (choice) = {
    securityData = {
        security = XXX XX Equity
        sequenceNumber = 0
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = 2016-08-18
                CUR_MKT_CAP = 117.7144
                PX_LAST = 1.06
                EQY_SH_OUT = 111.051
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I changed the ticker to XXX XX on purpose. =D